# What is the equivalent of File.ReadAllBytes of C# in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs

In C# we do

```
 byte[] barray = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\1.png");
```

It reads the content of the binary file to a byte array

What is the equivalent of this in AngularJS

I am trying

```
var x = new Uint8Array('images/1.jpg');             
console.log(x);
```

But error

[image]

Comment: Where are you expecting to load the file from?

Comment: Sir,  from local system... I am actually expecting the byte array in AngularJS like we get in C#

Comment: Well the code is running on the user's browser - what access to their file system are you expecting? You shouldn't expect raw access to the whole disk, for example...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileReader API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader). However, IE does not currently support the `readAsBinaryString()` method. You can, however, use `readAsDataURL()` if you wish to do things like preview local images before uploading.

K. Scott Allen has a nice little service he put together [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/03/building-a-filereader-service-for-angularjs-the-service.aspx).